# Does defaulting save_new_url still work?

Tags: button-overrides, save-and-new

I see other posts that suggest populating the save_new_url will direct the user to a page other than the standard new for the record you are creating, but I can't get this to work.  I go to this URL: https://cs16.salesforce.com/003/e?retURL=%2F003%2Fo&save_new_url=/006/e and would expect the Save & New button to take me to a new Opportunity page instead of another new Contact page.  But it doesn't, I am just taken to a new Contact.
I wondered if the ability to prepopulate this value is no longer available in the same way we can populate saveURL and retURL.

Comment: I would expect the value of `save_new_url` to be URLEncoded i.e. `%2F006%2Fe` though that may not be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Same result with the encoding.  When I look at the page source it does show my save_new_url override but when I click Save & New it seems to be ignored.  
<input type="hidden" name="cancelURL" id="cancelURL" value="/003/o" />
<input type="hidden" name="retURL" id="retURL" value="/003/o" />
<input type="hidden" name="save_new_url" id="save_new_url" value="/006/e" />